# How can a required field in bigquery be nullable in a select?

Tags: google-bigquery

I doing some meta programming with bigquery and noticed something I didn't expect.

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare` LIMIT 1000
```

which should go against a public dataset. If you analyze that query you would see that the schema looked like this:

```
"schema": {
"fields": [
 {
  "name": "word",
  "type": "STRING",
  "mode": "NULLABLE"
 },
 {
  "name": "word_count",
  "type": "INTEGER",
  "mode": "NULLABLE"
 },
 {
  "name": "corpus",
  "type": "STRING",
  "mode": "NULLABLE"
 },
 {
  "name": "corpus_date",
  "type": "INTEGER",
  "mode": "NULLABLE"
 }
]
},
```

This might look good at first, but if you look at the table definition for `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare` you will notice that the every field in that select are required in the table, so why does it end up being nullable in the schema for the select?

Some context:

I'm working on a F# type provider wher I try to encode all the values as correct as possible. That means nullable as option types and non nullable as regular types. If I always get nullable it will make the use much more cumbersome for fields that can't be nullable.

Answer (score 0):

Even though fields are `REQUIRED` in the table schema, query can do transformations which converts non `NULL` values to `NULL` values, therefore query result may have different schema (both with respect to nullability and to data types) then what the original table had.

Comment: That I know, but the query analyzer should be able to figure out if the transformed value can be null or not. Isn't there a way to say "force" to make the analyzer to check that as well.

Comment: I'm coming from mssql land and I am pretty sure you get that there.

Comment: Added some context on what I'm working on in the question.

Comment: There is no way to force it on a query. If you need to get schema of the table including NULLABLE constraint, you should use APIs, not SQL - i.e. "bq show <table>"

Comment: I know I can get it for a table, but I really can't understand the limitation.

Comment: Yes, it is a limitation - you can open bug about it in public issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149

Comment: Will do later this week. Thanks.

Comment: @TomasJansson did you end up creating an issue, and did anything come of it? I'm running into the same thing and it's pretty disappointing :( 
Even adding an explicit `WHERE field_name IS NOT NULL` doesn't cause the mode to be inferred as REQUIRED in the schema.

Comment: @chmod_007, yes I did and it resulted in nothing so I stopped me side project which only made sense if I had the correct schema.